# How to setup a click handler for something that doesn't have a click event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an `Icon` via the `ErrorProvider` component (as it's not a `Control` per se). I want to hook a click handler onto the icon itself. When it displays I want to let my users click on it and generate a detail flyout or help article-ish interface to provide detail. It exposes an `IntPtr` handle, but I'm not versed well at all in the Win32 world. I'm thinking that's what I need (something with `WndProc`, maybe??) because I've tried adding a click even on the form containing the control but that didn't cut it.

How do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Use spy++ and tell me if the Icon is a window itself or not

Comment: I'm not sure that it's even a possibility but you can think about putting a Control on the same position as the `Icon` and then catch clicks on that Control.

Comment: look here for the solution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/1e96e271-f619-4a1c-b1a5-0d027651607f/how-to-make-an-errorprovider-clickable ... but you have to understand that this is not a good practice

Comment: @GeorgeLica Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/KEwj0Ge.png. I would guess so since Spy++ says "Window" on the result line. But, as I said, I'm not versed in Win32 stuff so I don't know.

Comment: @lem2802 Thank you. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I have never tried doing this, but if you are willing to go to that much trouble (and testing) to get this effect, you might consider instead implementing your own ErrorProvider.  Just a thought.

Comment: @AnnL. That's something I've considered. The only objectionable part in my mind is that since the native ErrorProvider goes anywhere near IntPtr's then I wonder if I could do a custom implementation justice and without leaks.

Comment: @lem2802 That certainly did the trick, and, yes, that is some gnarly code. I need to do some research on the implications of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ErrorProvider dynamically creates windows to display the error icon.  Detecting mouse clicks on those windows requires very nasty code.  I'll just show you how it is done, I recommend you don't actually use it.  Start a new WF app and drop a text box and an error provider on the form.  Paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
      errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Test");
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
      Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
      base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
      if (m.Msg == 0x201) {
        // MouseDown, check if the icon was clicked
        NativeWindow wnd = NativeWindow.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
        if (wnd == null) return false;
        Type t = wnd.GetType();
        if (t.Name != "ErrorWindow") return false;
        // Yes, use Reflection to find the control for that icon
        FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        System.Collections.ArrayList items = fi.GetValue(wnd) as System.Collections.ArrayList;
        if (items == null || items.Count == 0) return false;
        object item = items[0];
        FieldInfo fi2 = item.GetType().GetField("control", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Control ctl = fi2.GetValue(item) as Control;
        // Got it.
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked the icon for " + ctl.Name);
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple errors displayed, this will only ever return the first control that has an error on it.  If you want to make the code even nastier, I suppose you could grab the current mouse coords and see which control  listed in the "items" array is nearest...